# Silverlight onLoad event doesn't fire in Firefox or Safari

Tags: javascript, silverlight, firefox, safari

I'm struggling with the Silverlight onLoad event in Firefox/Safari. In IE they fire as they should but in FF/Safari they don't.

I create the Silverlight object from JavaScript supplying the necessary params incl the onError and onLoad events. I've omitted some parts of the code below for readability.

Am I missing something or do I need some workaround for making the onLoad event to kick in other browsers than IE?

Thank you in advance!

```
Silverlight.createObject(
    "silverlight/MediaPlayer.xap?verison=16012013",
    _container,
    "silverlightControl",
    params,
    {
        onError: onSilverlightError,
        onLoad: onSilverlightLoaded
    },
    {},
    context
);

var onSilverlightLoaded = function (sender, context, slObject) {
    var slHost = slObject.getHost();
    // Do stuff
};

var onSilverlightError = function (sender, args) {
    console.debug("Oups...");
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the error was my own. The initParams parameteter for the createObject method needs to be a string, not an object for the Silverlight plugin to initialize correctly in Firefox and Safari (see below). IE doesn't seem to bother.

```
Silverlight.createObject(
    "silverlight/MediaPlayer.xap?verison=16012013",
    _container,
    "silverlightControl",
    params,
    {
        onError: onSilverlightError,
        onLoad: onSilverlightLoaded
    },
    "",
    context
);

var onSilverlightLoaded = function (sender, context, slObject) {
    var slHost = slObject.getHost();
    // Do stuff
};

var onSilverlightError = function (sender, args) {
    console.debug("Oups...");
};
```